# Cannot compile OpenCV code (C++)

Tags: c++, opencv, compilation, makefile, g++

Okay, so I have been searching for this problem for a while, and I still am clueless as to how to solve it.

I am trying to run the sample code available here: http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d1/dc5/tutorial_background_subtraction.html.
I understand the code. I just cannot get it to compile! The problem is with **library includes**. Here's my `Makefile`:

```
CFLAGS = `pkg-config --cflags opencv`
LIBS = `pkg-config --libs opencv`

% : %.cpp
    g++ $(CFLAGS) $(LIBS) -o $@ $<
```

Here's the **error**:

```
prakhar@inS4n3 ~/dev/gender recognition $ make bs
g++ `pkg-config --cflags opencv` `pkg-config --libs opencv` -o bs bs.cpp
bs.cpp:2:33: fatal error: opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp: No such file or directory
 #include "opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp"
                                 ^
compilation terminated.
Makefile:5: recipe for target 'bs' failed
make: *** [bs] Error 1
```

If I (for the time being) comment out this file, I get a similar error with `imgproc.hpp`. In another of my `OpenCV` code, **the following compiles prefectly**:

```
#include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"
#include "opencv2/contrib/contrib.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
```

As far as I can tell, replacing `opencv2/core.hpp` with `opencv2/core/core.hpp` or replacing `opencv2/imgproc.hpp` with `opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp` does the job.

So I looked deeper and here's my `opencv2` folder:

```
prakhar@inS4n3 /usr/include/opencv2 $ ll
total 84
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Nov 14 19:42 calib3d
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Nov 14 19:42 contrib
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Nov 14 19:42 core
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Nov 14 19:42 features2d
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Nov 14 19:42 flann
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Nov 14 19:42 gpu
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Nov 14 19:42 highgui
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Nov 14 19:42 imgproc
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Nov 14 19:42 legacy
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Nov 14 19:42 ml
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Nov 14 19:42 nonfree
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Nov 14 19:42 objdetect
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Nov 14 19:42 ocl
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2751 Oct  1  2014 opencv.hpp
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  672 Nov 12 00:02 opencv_modules.hpp
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Nov 14 19:42 photo
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Nov 14 19:42 stitching
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Nov 14 19:42 superres
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Nov 14 19:42 ts
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Nov 14 19:42 video
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Nov 14 19:42 videostab
```

**Can anyone tell me why this is happening, and how do I get the `imgcodecs.hpp` and `videoio.hpp` modules?**
I am using `OpenCV` `2.4.10-2`, on Arch Linux.

Comment: just include "opencv2/opencv.hpp" ... everything else is included within

Comment: Hi, I get an error `bs.cpp:52:44: error: ‘createBackgroundSubtractorMOG2’ was not declared in this scope` so probably I need something else?

Comment: compare to answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19221877/opencv-how-to-use-createbackgroundsubtractormog

Answer (score 3):

Okay, with help from @Micka, I finally realized that the doc is for OpenCV `3.0 beta`, not `2.4.10`. As such, making the changes in [this](http://docs.opencv.org/master/db/dfa/tutorial_transition_guide.html) solves the problem.

However, I simply installed the 3.0 beta, and that worked fine.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19221877/opencv-how-to-use-createbackgroundsubtractormog)'s the transtition guide, which for me was hard-to-find (still don't know why!).