# I want to Create MEX-File from OpenCV C++ file but it dosen`t work

Tags: c++, matlab, opencv, mex

I use Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 , MATLAB R2016a And OpenCV 3.1ver. i have some OpenCV c++ file. I want to create MEX-File from OpenCV C++ file and i use

```
    mexOpenCV myfile.cpp
```

on MATLAB.

And Error is poped like this

```
    다음 사용 중 오류가 발생함: mexOpenCV (line 122)
    소스.cpp
    C:\Users\USER\Desktop\같은색 마커\같은색 마커\소스.cpp(5): fatal error
    C1083: 포함 파일을 열 수 없습니다. 'opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp': No such file
    or directory
```

how can i solve this problem?

Comment: you have to include `opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp`...have a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30199086/cannot-compile-opencv-code-c

Comment: The [OpenCV support included](http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ug/opencv-interface.html) with the Computer Vision System toolbox only works with the prebuilt opencv libraries shipped with MATLAB (I believe opencv 2.4.9 in R2016a). If you want to work with the latest opencv 3.1.0 (or even opencv 2.x), check out mexopencv: https://github.com/kyamagu/mexopencv.